# Using both @RequestBody and normal parameters

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3 controllers with a flex client.
I am now using @RequestBody in order to pass xml's to the server.
How can i pass additional parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix and match easily enough:

```
public String handle(@RequestBody String xml, @RequestParam String x, @RequestParam String y) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: but how do i differentiate the parameters from the body? (if using POST). The body will contain the xml, so where do the params go?

Comment: @Noam: They must go in the URL, they can't be POST parameters. If this is your question, then it has nothing to do with Spring, it's a more basic question of mixing POST parameters with a request body.

Comment: Thank you skaffman, that was not clear to me. I thought i could mix the body and the params.